# How to Get order increment id in an email title in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, email, email-templates

Can someone tell me how to get the order increment id in the email template subject in Magento 2. In Magento 1 we got it with:

```
{{var order.increment_id}}
```

Answer (score 6):

you can call like below in email template subject with increment id,

```
{{trans "%increment_id," increment_id=$order.getIncrementId()}}
```